# Knowledgebase/file sharing web application

Tags: share

looking for an opensource project similar to OWL (http://owl.anytimecomm.com/)

What we need is an online app to allow for file sharing and collaboration.  We need an application to replace current klunky ftp solution providing people with options to email links to public files, etc

What does everyone use?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.nuxeo.com/en/products/document-management ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try

- http://www.nuxeo.com/en/products/document-management/
- http://www.alfresco.com/

In my experience Alfresco is really complex solution, but also offers lots of features. Nuxeo is more simple and has a more usable UI.

Comment: thanks!  Have you tried OpenKM?  will try nuxeo :)

Comment: I haven't! If you can add an small comparison will be appreciate.

Comment: there is also OWL... which does not seem to do a key thing... be able to share a file with a user outside the app :(

Comment: Nuxeo appers to be an excellent choice, however, it does not play well with your own Tomcat cluster... Will give Alfresco a shot